# Обновление progress bar из другого контроллера

Tags: java, javafx

Здравствуйте.

Начал осваивать javaFX недавно и столкнулся с проблемой если сцена состоит из 2-х панелей в разных FXML, в первой есть прогресс бар, во втором кнопка которая запускает updateProgress, но при запуске вылетает ошибка JavaFX Application Thread.
Хотелось бы узнать что делать в этой ситуации.

Main:

```
package testFX_2;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Main extends Application {
private Stage stage;
private VBox vBox;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    this.stage = stage;
    this.stage.setResizable(false);
    this.stage.setTitle("Test2");

    rootPane();
    secondPane();

}


private void rootPane() throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/UI_main.fxml"));
    vBox = (VBox) loader.load();
    Scene scene = new Scene(vBox);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

private void  secondPane() throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/UI_second.fxml"));
    VBox anchorPane = (VBox) loader.load();
    vBox.getChildren().add(anchorPane);
   }
}
```

UI_mainController:

```
package testFX_2.view;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;

public class UI_mainController {

@FXML
public ProgressBar bar;
}
```

UI_main.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity"    minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="300.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="testFX_2.view.UI_mainController">
<children>
  <ProgressBar fx:id="bar" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="300.0" progress="0.0" />
   </children>
  </VBox>
```

UI_secondController:

```
package testFX_2.view;

import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class UI_secondController {



@FXML
private Button bar_btn;


@FXML
public void onClickBar(){
    Task<Integer> task = new Task<Integer>() {
        @Override
        protected Integer call() throws Exception {
            int max = 1000;
            for (int i = 0; i <max; i++) {
                updateProgress(i,max);
                Thread.sleep(20);
            }
            return  max;
        }
    };

    UI_mainController main = new UI_mainController();
    main.bar.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
    new Thread(task).start();
}

}
```

UIsecond.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="101.0" prefWidth="300.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="testFX_2.view.UI_secondController">
  <children>
  <Button fx:id="bar_btn" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onClickBar" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="300.0" text="BAR" />
  </children>
  </VBox>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну самое первое замечание - ты не должен создавать UI_mainController. За тебя это делает сам javafx.
Что тебе надо - это просунуть ссылку на этот контроллер, и из него уже взять прогресс бар и биндить

Должно быть что-то типо такого

Main.java

```
public class Main extends Application {

private UI_mainController firstController;
     ...
private void rootPane() throws IOException {
   FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
   loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/UI_main.fxml"));
   vBox = (VBox) loader.load();
   Scene scene = new Scene(vBox);
   this.firstController = loader.getController();
   stage.setScene(scene);
   stage.show();
}

private void  secondPane() throws IOException {
   FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
   loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/UI_second.fxml"));
   VBox anchorPane = (VBox) loader.load();
   loader.getController().setMainController(this.firstController);
   vBox.getChildren().add(anchorPane);
}
}
```

UI_secondController:

```
package testFX_2.view;

import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class UI_secondController {

UI_mainController mainController;

public void setMainController(MainController main) {
   this.mainController = main;
}

@FXML
private Button bar_btn;


@FXML
public void onClickBar(){
    Task<Integer> task = new Task<Integer>() {
        @Override
        protected Integer call() throws Exception {
            int max = 1000;
            for (int i = 0; i <max; i++) {
                Platform.runLater(() -> updateProgress(i,max))
                Thread.sleep(20);
            }
            return  max;
        }
    };

    main.bar.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
    new Thread(task).start();
}

}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, на основе этого примера дописал код и всё работает)))